# Check which ECHO comes with ajax success

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I do have two kind of `echo` in my ajax processing script. One for error messages and other one for form processing success.

This is how its look.

```
if (strlen($password) != 128) {
        $errorMsg  = "<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissible' role='alert'>\n";
        $errorMsg .=        "<strong>Oops!</strong> System error, Invalid password configuration.\n";
        $errorMsg .= "</div>\n";
        echo $errorMsg;
}
```

And other one is

```
// Print a message based upon the result:
if ($stmt->affected_rows == 1) {                
    // Print a message and wrap up:
    $successMsg  = "<div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissible' role='alert'>\n";
    $successMsg .=      "Your password has been changed. You will receive the new, temporary password at the email address with which you registered. Once you have logged in with this password, you may change it by clicking on the 'Password Modification' link.\n";
    $successMsg .= "</div>\n";
    echo $successMsg;   
}
```

So, I am using one `DIV` to populate these message upon the ajax success.

My question is, is there a way to identify which message is displaying with ajax success?

Hope somebody may help me out. 
Thank you.

Comment: Once you populate message to DIV, then you can find class by using some thing like ``$('.alert').hasClass('alert-success')`` or ``$('.alert').hasClass('alert-danger')``

Answer (score 3):

You can use `filter()` to see if the response has the class of `.alert-danger`:

```
// $.ajax({ ...
success: function(html) {
    var $html = $(html);
    if ($html.filter('.alert-danger').length) {
        // something went wrong
    }
    else {
        // it worked
    }
}
```

Note however, that a better pattern to use would be to return JSON containing the message to display, along with the class of the alert and a flag to indicate its state. Something like this:

```
var $arr;

if (strlen($password) != 128) {
    $arr = array('success'=>false,'cssClass'=>'alert-danger','message'=>'Oops! System error, Invalid password configuration.');
}

if ($stmt->affected_rows == 1) {
    $arr = array('success'=>true,'cssClass'=>'alert-success','message'=>'Your password has been changed. You will receive the new, temporary password at the email address with which you registered. Once you have logged in with this password, you may change it by clicking on the Password Modification link.');
}

echo json_encode($arr);
```

```js
// $.ajax({ ...
success: function(json) {
    if (json.success) {
        // it worked
    }
    else {
        // something went wrong
    }

    // append the alert
    $('#myElement').append('<div class="alert alert-dismissible + ' + json.cssClass + '" role="alert">' + json.message + '</div>');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for nice answer. Can you kindly tell me how to code in IF and ELSE part. I mean here `if (json.success) {
        // it worked
    }
    else {
        // something went wrong
    }`

Comment: Your question doesn't say what you want to do in those cases, so I can't really guide you on that.

Comment: IF this true  `if ($stmt->affected_rows == 1) { }` then I need to hide my form and should be display success message. If not I need to display error messages..

Comment: Rory McCrossan, I am trying to display error messages according to your section method. But I can not get the messages. This is my code `    success: function (json) {     
     if (json.success) {
      // it worked
      alert('ok');
     }
     else {
      // something went wrong
      //alert('not ok');       
      $('#message').append('<div class="alert alert-dismissible + ' + json.cssClass + '" role="alert">' + json.message + '</div>');
     }
    }`

Comment: Rory, Can you kindly help me to figure this out. Thank you.

Comment: What you have seems fine. Try checking the console for errors. If you still have issues, try opening a new question for that issue.

Comment: Have you checked the length of `$password` in PHP?

Comment: Hello, Rory, I asked my problem in another question and this is the like to it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31181108/display-user-messages-upon-ajax-success