# Display user messages upon ajax success

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to display two kind of user messages upon jquery/ajax response.

In my processing script I store these messages like this:

```
// Initialize Json array.
$messages ='';

   // Check for the email: 
    if (!empty($_POST['email'])) {  
        $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        $email = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            // Not a valid email
            $messages = array('success'=>false,'cssClass'=>'alert-danger','message'=>'Email does not match the required format.');

        }

    // Print a message based upon the result:
    if ($stmt->affected_rows == 1) {                
        // Print a message and wrap up:
        $messages = array('success'=>true,'cssClass'=>'alert-success','message'=>'Your password has been changed. You will receive the new, temporary password at the email address with which you registered. Once you have logged in with this password, you may change it by clicking on the "Password Modification" link.');
    }

    echo json_encode($messages);
```

In Jquery I am trying to populate these message something like this. But I cannot print out those messages.

**UPDATE:**

```
success: function (json) {                  
    if (json.success) {
        // it worked
        alert('ok');
        $('#message').append('<div class="alert alert-dismissible ' + json.cssClass + '" role="alert">' + json.message + '</div>');
        $('#message').show();                           

    } else {
        // something went wrong
        alert('not ok');    
        $('#message').append('<div class="alert alert-dismissible ' + json.cssClass + '" role="alert">' + json.message + '</div>');
        $('#message').show();       

    }
```

Can anybody tell me where I am going wrong? 
Hope somebody may help me out.

Thank you.

Comment: @Daan, no its always going to `else` part..

Comment: add `echo json_encode($messages);` at the end of your php page.

Comment: Yes its already there... updated question

Comment: I believe your problem is that `array('success'=>false...` part. you said if (json.success) but rather check for `if(json.success === false)` that way at least it will work if your 1st `if` is the result

Comment: If it is always going to the else part then the data must not include `success: true`. You haven't shown us enough code to tell why that is.

Comment: @Quentin, This conditon is true `if ($stmt->affected_rows == 1) {  }` when it is executing.

Comment: @user3733831 — The outcome you describe suggests otherwise. How are you determining that that condition is true?

Comment: I used this script to change my password. So my password is changing when this scrip is running.. And also I am checking, giving invalid email address to get my error message.. But I can get neither one

Comment: you dont have a global variable with a default for `$messages` if `POST['email']` is not left out and `affected_rows != 1` edit:I didnt refresh in time for this to be useful

Comment: This is what I can get to `#message` DIV. `<div id="message" style="display: block;">
<div class="alert alert-dismissible undefined" role="alert">undefined</div>
</div>`

Comment: I updated my question again. Check ajax success function

Comment: Please add the `header("Content-type : application/json")` before messages ='';

Comment: instead of json.success  try  eval(json.success)

Comment: When you console.log(json), does it show an [Object] or does it show a string that looks like the object?

Comment: @user3733831 hmm then it means the properties are undefined. which means they dont exist. probably not the type you are expecting. see below answers. eg trying to get `{" 'success':true"}.success` will give you `undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just missing one line of code.

What the server script is providing is JSON **string**.

And you cannot access properties from JSON **string**.

You have to parse the JSON **string** first and create a JSON **object** out of it.

```
success: function (jsonString) {
var json = JSON.parse(jsonString);         //parse the JSON string and create JSON object
if (json.success) {
    // it worked
    alert('ok');
    $('#message').append('<div class="alert alert-dismissible ' + json.cssClass + '" role="alert">' + json.message + '</div>');
    $('#message').show();
} else {
    // something went wrong
    alert('not ok');
    }
}
```

The above code uses `JSON` class available in `JS Platform`

Comment: @Sarfaraaz It is necessary, as `JSON.parse()` is missing in the code provided in the question. On adding that into the code, it is working fine.

Comment: thats not what I meant. I was wondering if this information was needed by the op or not. meaning "I assumed they knew that a json string needed to be parsed"

Comment: I explained it because I found it missing in the code provided by OP (Original Poster). And a little extra information is never bad.

Answer (score 1):

Use [parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) on the return data:

```
if (json) {
  json = $.parseJSON(json);
  alert(json.success);
}
```